# how die or print mysql has gone away error exact reason?

Tags: php, mysql

i have a php file that whenever i want send a post getting this error :
MYSQL ERROR:103 MySQL server has gone away

in line 101-103 in my php file i have this code :

```
$res2=mysql_query("select id from `news_tmp` where `fid`=$row[id] and `sign`='$hatitle' limit 1");
$res1_2=mysql_query("select id from `news_tmp` where `sign`='$hatitle' limit 3");
if(mysql_error()){echo "MYSQL ERROR:".__LINE__ . ' '.mysql_error();}else{
```

and line 103 is this :

```
if(mysql_error()){echo "MYSQL ERROR:".__LINE__ . ' '.mysql_error();}else{
```

now i want find reason of problem and why having mysql has gone away error.
I know that the problem could be one of two things max time or pocket size But I do not know exactly which of the two things is my problem.

please help me and tell how i can to print of the exactly problem.

thanks all.

Comment: first of all please stop deprecated as well as removed `mysql_*` library. switch to `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Comment: If you want know which of the two lines has error write `mysql_query(...) or die( 'Error '.mysql_error().' at line '.__LINE__ )` in each query line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You want to find out which line has error you can use `die(mysql_error())` like below:

```
$res2=mysql_query("select id from `news_tmp` where `fid`=$row[id] and `sign`='$hatitle' limit 1") or die(mysql_error());
$res1_2=mysql_query("select id from `news_tmp` where `sign`='$hatitle' limit 3") or die(mysql_error());
```